# Should we edit or comment information that forms the basis of another's question?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions, citing-sources

When I know what another user's question is based on, should I leave them a comment, telling them to edit this source into their question, or should I just go ahead and edit it?

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53196/5323), at least in its first (current) revision appears to be one of those. The question asks

> Did Yael bear a son from the relations she had with Sisra? If so, was he a prophet?

A commenter [asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53196/child-from-the-relations-yael-had-with-sisra#comment140895_53196)

> how do you know she had relations with him? I don't recall the pasuk saying so. Please edit in your responses.

to which I [responded](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53196/child-from-the-relations-yael-had-with-sisra#comment140897_53196)

> [Shoftim 5:27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15813#v=27), according to the explanation found at [Yevamos 103a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=103&format=pdf) (bottom, in the name of רבי יוחנן).

Should I leave that information in the comments, or should that be edited into the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the ability to improve the quality of the question without taking away from its intended meaning, [you should go ahead and do so](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3423/2).

In this case, the question would certainly be improved by the addition of sources for its assumptions, as indicated by multiple comments to that effect. The only reason I can think of not to add a source would be if its possible that there are multiple choices of source available, and the one you're adding adds some undesirable effect, such as causing a distraction from the actual question, if it's a controversial source. Here, you're sourcing with the interpretation of a verse in Tanach by a passage in the Talmud, which is pretty basic, authoritative, and presumably without controversy. I say go for it.

Answer (score 4):

I think that that's important information that should be in the question body itself. Quite obvious, as i was the one who asked the OP to edit in the source. :)

[From the help center:](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

Comment: Hey! I was going to do [that edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/53196/revisions) .....was just waiting to see if there would be any dissenting opinion here.

Comment: It hit HNQ, i didn't want to leave it low-quality.

Comment: Oh really? ....I didn't realize. Well done :)